# Using Python in Visual Studio for automation testing, but Selenium is not recognized

Tags: python, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nuget-package

I am new to Python in Visual Studio for automation testing. It seems Selenium library was not imported properly. Can anyone help me?

Reproduce steps:

1. Installed the newest version of Python.
2. Pip installed Selenium.
3. Installed Visual Studio Enterprise and Community (with .NET, Python Development, Node.js).

Started in Visual Studio with a new project in Python application. But then Selenium is not recognized by Visual Studio. I was trying to import Selenium library from Project\ManageNugetPackages, but this option was GreyOut.

Can anyone help me?

[Selenium issue not recognized.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjuKW.jpg)

[Visual Studio Error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84az3.jpg)

[Error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caBNX.jpg)

[Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngtXy.png)

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Comment: I have never used python and VS but my guess is that pip install will conflict with NuGet installs. My suggestion would be to undo the pip install and just use NuGet. You have to click on a Project (not a Solution) to be able to manage NuGet packages.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to install python packages in Visual Studio

Right click on python environment and click Install Python Package
[image]

Then in Python Environments explorer search for the package and click the link to install.
[image]