# Why cannot I import selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, import

Why can't I import selenium?
My text is looking like this in Visual Studio code:
[image]

I have not always had this problem. The problem occurred after I switched to Windows 11 where the c-drive was deleted.

Do someone out there know how to fix it?

I'm using Windows 11.

Comment: Did you install the package?

Comment: i think its because vs code extensions, showing grammatical mistakes.

Comment: What package? Because when I'm trying to install the selenium in my cmd it says `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: ya @RobertTacchini its the package

Comment: So no it's not installed

Comment: Did you reinstall Python on your new Windows 11?

Comment: Yes I did install it for new.

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154250/using-python-in-visual-studio-for-automation-testing-but-selenium-is-not-recogn

Comment: No, because I already have downloaded the extensions to Visual Studio Code. 
I think the problem occurs because I have not downloaded selenium to my pc / cmd.

Comment: Sounds like a config issue rather than a code issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `C:> py -m ensurepip --upgrade`
If you install Python correctly it'll fix your problem with pip.
Or download script from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run `C:> py get-pip.py`
Read official site [Installation - pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)

After that try to run `pip install -U selenium` (-U to upgrade it if it exsists)
If it didn't help then download official archive from [here](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files) and then run command `python setup.py install`

If that didn't work try to `pip uninstall selenium` reboot your PC and do it again. Hope it works

Comment: Okay thanks. Now the pip is working and selenium is downloaded. But I still get the yellow line under the imports.

Comment: I recommend just reinstall, the windows python installer has become quite robust and will try to clean up before installing. then when finished add a `python -m venv <your workdir>; <your workdir>\Scripts\Activate.ps1`, then install selenium and your packages in this venv and create a `requirements.txt` package file for the future, then you can delete and reinstall as you like.

Comment: I'm not sure. But what you saying its I'm gonna uninstall python and install it again. Then run this commnad in the cmd `python -m venv <your workdir>; <your workdir>\Scripts\Activate.ps1`. And after that should I install the selenium package `pip install selenium` and then create a requirments.txt package file for the future?

Comment: @RobertTacchini I think the yellow light it's about the VSCode features. Don't worry if it's all working. Maybe it happens cuz windows 11 are too young